# Right way to zurb's foundation 6 destroy and reinitialize on ember

Tags: dom, ember.js, components, zurb-foundation, dom-manipulation

i am trying to do destroy and reinitialize foundation 6 component in ember app. Currently i did these below. It works on the first click after that it won't trigger reinitialize:

```
// components/zf-reveal.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    Ember.Logger.log('open');
    this.set('reveal', new Foundation.Reveal(this.$('.reveal')));
  },
  willDestroyElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    Ember.Logger.log('destroy');
    this.get('reveal').destroy();
  }
});

// templates/components/zf-reveal.hbs
<a data-open="modal">OPEN REVEAL</a>
<div class="reveal" id="modal" data-reveal>
  <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
  <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

These snippets do destroy on route change but when i try to click it again after route change it's not reappearing wont even sending error message

Comment: You can keep it in last `this._super(...arguments);` in `willDestroyElement` hook. Just to remind you that didInsertElement will be called only once in life time of the components.

Comment: @kumkanillam after `willDestroyElement` called entire components are removed from DOM right?

Comment: Yes. but we still have two hooks on component will be called on destroy after willDestroyElement .https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_on-component-destroy

Comment: in that case is it alright to reinitialize(didInsertElement) again? like didInsertElement called again is it?

Comment: Yes. You are right. We should not manually call life cycle hook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149964/discussion-between-kumkanillam-and-zorig).

Answer (score 0):

So far as @kumkanillam said and changed it a little bit got this result and it works.

```
//components/zf-reveal.js
/* global Foundation */
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('reveal', new Foundation.Reveal(this.$('.reveal')));
  },
  willDestroyElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('reveal').destroy();
  },
  actions: {
    openModal(){
      this.get('reveal').open();
    }
  }
});

//templates/components/zf-reveal.hbs
<a onclick={{action 'openModal'}}>OPEN REVEAL</a>
<div class="reveal" id="modal" data-reveal>
  <h1>Awesome. I Have It.</h1>
  <p class="lead">Your couch. It is mine.</p>
  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
  <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```